# Alert "you have started editing or writing a post" when I've not

Tags: bug, status-completed, review-queues

Today I was doing some reviews on the first posts queue. At some point, I was editing a post and I accidentally pressed del on my keyboard going to the page before. That page was correctly showing a review I did and didn't allow me to cast the vote. So, I clicked next and I've got a new post and I've continued reviewing it. When the queue got cleared, although, I've got this alert:

[image]

As soon as I clicked on everything that should have redirect me. I think the problem is that for some reason, it's still thinking I am still editing that post even if I'm not.

I thought I should report this. I'm using Google Chrome. If you need any other information, feek free to ask.

Comment: "I accidentally pressed del on my keyboard going to the page before" - did you mean backspace?

Comment: Yes I actually meant backspace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *actual* [bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bug) here was that you didn't get that popup when you accidentally pressed <kbd>backspace</kbd>.

A fix for this will be rolling out in the next build (build rev `2016.5.3.4464` on MSE/MSO, `2016.5.3.3531` on sites).